# Does DDR3 ram need to be installed in pairs?

Tags: memory, ddr3, amd-athlon

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Matched DRAM — Why? Is it important?](https://superuser.com/questions/283727/matched-dram-why-is-it-important)

I'm building a machine with the following motherboard and processor.

MSI 890FXA-GD65 Socket AM3/ AMD 890FX/ DDR3/ SATA3&USB3.0/ A&GbE/ ATX Motherboard
  AMD Athlon II X2 Dual-Core Processor 240 (2.8 GHz) AM3
  1GB DDR3-1333 PC3-10600

Do I need multiple DIMMs for this setup to function?

Answer (score 7):

Not necessarily, but installing memory in matched pairs will ensure optimum performance.  A computer will function with only one module or with modules with different sizes or speeds, but performance will be less than optimal; furthermore, if memory with different speeds are used, both modules will be limited to that of the slower module.  If matched pairs are used, they can work together to increase performance, but you can operate a modern computer with only one memory module.  For more information, see the Wikipedia article on [dual-channel architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual-channel_architecture).